# adding delimiters to end of file

Tags: perl, file, delimiter

I am working on a TPT script to process some large files we have. Right now, each record length in the file has a delimiter, `|`.

The problem is that not all fields are used by each record. For example, record 1 may have 100 fields and record 2 may have 260. For TPT to work, we need to have a delimiter for each field, so the records that have less than 261 fields populated, I need to append the appropriate number of pipes to the end of each record.

So, taking my example above, record one would have 161 pipes appended to the end and record two would have 1.

I have a perl script which will count the number of pipes in each record, but I am not sure how to take that info and accomplish the task of appending that many pipes to the field.

```
perl -ne 'print scalar(split(/\|/, $_)) . "\n"'
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of pipe symbols, you can use the `tr` operator.

```
my $count = tr/|//;
```

Just subtract the number of pipe symbols from the maximal number to get the number of pipes to add, use the `x` (times) operator to get them:

```
perl -lne 'print $_, "|" x (260 - tr/|//)'
```

I'm not sure the number is correct, it depends on whether the pipes also start or end the line.